# Python configparser read a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

I was wondering if there is a way to establish a dictionary in a config file and use python config parser to read it?

Thanks.

Comment: Pickle it. INI files aren't very versatile.

Comment: [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) is a module that lets you convert a Python object into a byte stream. Basically, you can make a `Configuration` class with all of your required options and then pickle it to a file. When you re-load it, it will be the same class you originally pickled.

Comment: Would it be an option to map the dictionary to a whole section in the config file, with the the keys of the dictionary mapped to configuration variables in that section?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I thought there would be a more efficient way. I guess i'll do that then.

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval` and simply execute the configuration file.

```
with open('the_config','r') as config_file:
    config= eval( config_file.read() )
```

You will see comments telling you this is evil and a security hole and lots of other things.  However, it's exactly as secure as your Python source.

Comment: @ParthG: "could you be more specific please".  Yes.  If you have a specific question, I can provide more specific information.  What confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

`configparser` does not support that, but maybe you could be interested in taking a look at the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html) module.

Adapting an example from the official [doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> s = json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
>>> print(s)
{
    "4": 5, 
    "6": 7
}
>>> json.loads(s)
{'4': 5, '6': 7}
```